# Re-submit current binary and IAP to App Store?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store

I had a binary rejected because I didn't submit the IAP for review at the same time.  So I re-submitted an IAP for review.  That was rejected because I didn't have a new binary at the same time (I thought I had to wait for the IAP to get approved because earlier there was a button to add the IAP to the binary, but now it wasn't there.. so I thought the IAP had to be approved first)

So they're saying to upload a new binary and re-submit a new IAP.  But if I delete the current IAP, it won't let me re-use the same product ID.  So I have to go back and tweak the file, re-create the IPA, re-process it at Enhance, mail it to my other computer etc etc.  The current binary and current IAP are totally fine and designed to work together.  Why/how in the world can't I just re-submit the same ones again???  I suppose I could just re-upload the same IPA, but I can't just re-make a new IAP without losing the current product ID.

How can I get around this?  Should I just submit an appeal and tell them to look at the latest build and latest IAP together manually?  Or, if it's not possible, could someone at least explain why they do things this way?  Is there some danger in letting someone re-use a rejected product ID?

Comment: You don't need to do anything to the IAPs. If the current build has been marked as binary rejected then you need to recompile and upload the same version but with a different build number. You can then submit it for review.

Comment: But that was a few steps ago. I submitted a new binary and it was rejected because the IAP was not "submitted at the same time" (it existed, it just wasn't submitted for review because I didn't realize you had to submit both separately yet simultaneously)

Comment: Submit the IAP for review and the submit the new binary for review while the IAP is pending review.

Comment: But there was no way to resubmit the IAP for review... only an option to delete it (which would take the product ID off the table)... until I read on another thread I found, to fiddle with the localization settings.  That hack actually worked and it changed the status back to "waiting for review".  I was then able to re-submit the last binary too.  So at least now both are pending something at the same time O.o

Comment: Yes, you just need to change the metadata so that you can resubmit it.